# ignite client connecting to the server

Tags: java, caching, server, ignite

> this is my code:

```
ClientConfiguration cfg = new ClientConfiguration()
               .setAddresses("127.0.0.1:10800")
               .setUserName("ignite")
               .setUserPassword("ignite");
 IgniteClient client = Ignition.startClient(cfg);
```

> this is my output:
>           [12:24:58,906][SEVERE][grid-nio-worker-client-listener-0-#29][ClientListenerProcessor] Failed to process selector key [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=ByteBufferNioClientWorker [readBuf=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=8192 cap=8192], super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=0, bytesRcvd=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd0=0, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-client-listener-0, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1582872897852, hashCode=106881139, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-client-listener-0-#29]]], writeBuf=null, readBuf=null, inRecovery=null, outRecovery=null, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/127.0.0.1:10800, rmtAddr=/127.0.0.1:65151, createTime=1582872897767, closeTime=0, bytesSent=75, bytesRcvd=33, bytesSent0=75, bytesRcvd0=33, sndSchedTime=1582872897852, lastSndTime=1582872897852, lastRcvTime=1582872897852, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter, GridNioCodecFilter [parser=ClientListenerBufferedParser, directMode=false]], accepted=true, markedForClose=false]]]

Comment: I can't figure out what you are actually after. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected output if you throw a connection on the floor, i.e. open it, never close and terminate your program (or let it be reclaimed by GC).

Comment: i am not terminating my program, it shows on server side immediately when i run the above client code

Comment: Well, have you tried doing anything with this client? Any exceptions on client side?

Comment: no i want just enable the authentication and connect the client with server

Comment: Why are you sure that it did not connect? Did you get any exception?

Comment: can you please send me the java client code for connecting to the ignite server, note in that server persistence is enabled,

Comment: You can use Ignite examples shipped along with binary distribution. See [ClientPutGetExample](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/client/ClientPutGetExample.java). If cluster is persistent, you will have to activate it first, for example by using `bin/control.sh --activate`